# slow update script in postgres

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a text file with 850000 individual update statements, updating a table containing 12 million records. An example of such a query is:

```
update bag.pand
set mutatiedatum = to_date('04-03-2013 10:03:48','DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS')
where key='0321100000015282_2013022600000000_N_0'
 ;
```

Where 'key' has a unique index on it.

I execute the file using psql.exe -q  -1 -f '/path/to/sql/file' on a 9.1 postgres/postgis database.

This is executing extremely slow: some 14-20 statements per second.

When I explain analyze a separate statement it is fast enough:

```
Update on pand  (cost=0.00..6.12 rows=1 width=814) (actual time=0.101..0.101 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using idx_pand_key on pand  (cost=0.00..6.12 rows=1 width=814) (actual time=0.093..0.093 rows=0 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((key)::text = '0321100000015282_2013022600000000_N_0'::text)
Total runtime: 0.237 ms
```

The log file contains no warnings or errors.

I understand that by using -f all 850000 statements are executed in one transaction. Could this be the reason for the slowness? Is there another solution or hint to speed things up?

Comment: What is the fraction of records you expect to touch with this update? (the explained plan touches 0 records)

Comment: 90-95% (on our production environment it should be 100%, but I am testing on my notebook, where the data is slightly older)

Comment: Is there an index on the `mutatiedatum` column? That would explain it.

Comment: BTW: ` 14-20 statements per second.` : you are executing this statement *repeatedly* (but with different values for the key and the timestamp - constants) ?

Comment: The 850k update statements will update all 12 million rows?

Comment: ... in that case `key` would not be unique, but there would be about 15 tuples per `key` value.

Comment: @Clodoaldo Neto there was a index on mutatiedatum (which there shouldn't at this stage). I removed it and restarted the script, but it improved slightly to 19 updates pers seconds.

Comment: @wilplasser and  Mike Sherrill 'Catcall': sure, the statements each update a different unique row, identified by `key`. So maximum is 850000 rows updated.

Comment: ok, meanwhile, back at the farm, I first did this: since I had interrupted several tries, I first vacuum-ed and analyzed the table pand. Ik also removed a handfull of other indexes on fields which were not updated at all. Now my the number of updates rose to some 60 per / seconds and then I had to leave for some family obligations. I do not only want to have a fast end result, but I also want to understand why the original approach was so slow. I am still puzzled why removal of indexes which are not touched by the update, has such an impact on performance....

Comment: I am impressed by the speed and qualitity of all of your contributions. I know reputation plays an important role here, so what do I have to show my appreciation for your help?

Comment: @HarmOlthof: Upvote good answers and comments. (Upvotes on comments don't change reputation.) You can upvote more than one. Accept the best answer.

Comment: @HarmOlthof: You said, *"I understand that by using -f all 850000 statements are executed in one transaction."* No, it's `-c`, not `-f`. [Source](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) If your system will tolerate splitting those 850k statements into smaller batches, you might find that batches of 10k to 50k statements run much faster. That is, run smaller batches in separate, smaller transactions. But beware the problems of rollback.

Answer (score 1):

If all the updates have the same shape, you could load them into a temp-table and use that to update the `bag.pand` table *in one batch* , like this:

```
CREATE TABLE bag.mutaties
        ( zkey varchar NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , zdate timestamp NOT NULL
        );
COPY bag.mutaties(zkey,zdate) FROM 'the_big_file';

update bag.pand dst
FROM bag.mutaties src
set mutatiedatum = src.zdate
WHERE dst.key = src.zkey
        ;
```

The above assumes the dates are in ISO 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' format.

If you are unable to create a data file with this date format, you could read the existing 'dd-mm-yyyy' dates into a string and convert them in the update statement (similar to your row-at-a-time updates:

```
CREATE TABLE bag.mutaties
        ( zkey varchar NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , dutchdate varchar NOT NULL
        );

COPY bag.mutaties(zkey,dutchdate) FROM 'the_big_file';

update bag.pand dst
FROM bag.mutaties src
set mutatiedatum = to_date(src.dutchdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS')
WHERE dst.key = src.key
        ;
```

**EXTRA BONUS UPDATE**:

```
        -- This will read in the existing SQL-SCRIPT (!!)
        -- and transform it into a table with {key,datetimestamp}
CREATE TABLE bag.tekstmutaties
        ( id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , typ INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
        , num INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
        , tekst varchar
        );

        -- Read in the existing script file
        -- (this needs to be in /tmp/ to avoid permission problems)
COPY bag.tekstmutaties(tekst) FROM '/tmp/bagmut.txt';

        -- Remove bagger
delete from bag.tekstmutaties
where LEFT(tekst,1) NOT IN ( 's' , 'w')
        ;

        -- Extract the timestamp
UPDATE bag.tekstmutaties
SET typ = 1
        , tekst = regexp_replace( tekst, E' *set.*to_date..', '', 'ig')
WHERE LEFT(tekst,1) IN ( 's')
        ;
UPDATE bag.tekstmutaties
SET tekst = LEFT( tekst , 19)
WHERE typ = 1
        ;

        -- Extract the key
UPDATE bag.tekstmutaties
SET typ = 2
        , tekst = regexp_replace( tekst, E' *where key..', '', 'ig')
WHERE LEFT(tekst,1) IN ( 'w')
        ;
UPDATE bag.tekstmutaties
SET tekst = regexp_replace( tekst , '[^0-9A-Z_]' , '' , 'g' )
WHERE typ = 2
        ;

        -- number the records
UPDATE bag.tekstmutaties
SET num = id
WHERE TYP=1
        ;
        -- number the records
UPDATE bag.tekstmutaties uu
SET num = src.val
FROM (
        SELECT id, lag(id) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS val
        FROM bag.tekstmutaties
        ) src
WHERE uu.TYP=2
AND src.id = uu.id
        ;

SELECT * FROM bag.tekstmutaties ORDER BY id;

        -- The final table with the {key,timestamp} pairs
CREATE TABLE bag.mutaties
        ( zkey varchar NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , zdate timestamp NOT NULL
        );

        -- Fill it with self-join of teksttable
INSERT INTO bag.mutaties (zkey, zdate)
SELECT k.tekst AS zkey
        , to_date(d.tekst, E'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS' ) AS zdate
FROM bag.tekstmutaties k
JOIN bag.tekstmutaties d ON k.num = d.num
WHERE k.typ=2
AND d.typ = 1
        ;
SELECT * FROM bag.mutaties;

-- now **after verification** you can use the mutaties-table
-- to batch-update the bag.pand table
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
update bag.pand dst
FROM mutaties src
set mutatiedatum = src.zdate
WHERE dst.key = src.key
        ;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this as a last resort. Because this would mean a considerable change to the current proces which creates the sqlfile.  So for now I still want to try the update statements.

Comment: The script is generated by another process? If you have enough skills with the editor, it would take <15 minutes to transform the script into a datafile. Otherwise create a small program to do the conversion. (theoretically, you could even do it in SQL, but that would be a major feat...)

Comment: true, but this is prob not a onetime operation.... I will let run the script until tomorrow if it hasn't finished by then I will try your solution. thanks.

Comment: I already created a script that eats up your .sql script and transforms it into data. BRB

Comment: I also tried your bonus update script (thanks!), but that didn't work: As far as I understand your script, you assume statements starting with "select ...", whereas my statements start with 'update', so I will have to adjust that and it's consequences in e.g. SET tekst = LEFT( tekst , 19). Next time!

Comment: No the script tries to match the `set ...` and the `where ...` lines, and extracts the key and value from them. and ignores any other lines. The match is quite course (and case- and space- sentitive) so you might need to tweak a little.

Comment: geen betrokkenheid bij kadaster of kvk voor deze vraag! Eigen interne motivatie....

Comment: BTW: the LEFT() could possibly fail because the preceding regexp assumes a fixed format. (I was too lazy to escape the `('` before the date+time  constant) With some work (and given a regular shaped input) it could be made to work.